# Function Array to String (Swift)

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

Hi I'm a Swift beginner and I'm trying to make a function that takes an array as input and converts it into a String. The array that I want to use is full of strings.

```
func arrayToString (_ x:Array<Any>) {
    let y = x.joined(separator: "") // error: Ambiguous reference to member 'joined()'
    return y
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The elements of `x` are of type `Any`, a type you'd generally want to avoid (unless forced to use due to being supplied `Any` objects from some API at runtime). Is it an option to let `x` be an array of `String` instances instead? (`[String]`). Also, you haven't supplied a return type to your function, so it is inferred to be `Void` (you want this to be `-> String`). If you stick with `x` being `[Any]`, you need to perform an attempted type conversion of each element in `x` to `String` prior to calling `joined(separator:)`, e.g. `return x.flatMap{ $0 as? String }.joined(separator: "")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Doc:

```
extension Array where Element == String {

    /// Returns a new string by concatenating the elements of the sequence,
    /// adding the given separator between each element.
    ///
    /// The following example shows how an array of strings can be joined to a
    /// single, comma-separated string:
    ///
    ///     let cast = ["Vivien", "Marlon", "Kim", "Karl"]
    ///     let list = cast.joined(separator: ", ")
    ///     print(list)
    ///     // Prints "Vivien, Marlon, Kim, Karl"
    ///
    /// - Parameter separator: A string to insert between each of the elements
    ///   in this sequence. The default separator is an empty string.
    /// - Returns: A single, concatenated string.
    public func joined(separator: String = default) -> String
}
```

It will only work with `Array<String>`

And your code should be:

```
func arrayToString (_ x:Array<String>) -> String {
    let y = x.joined(separator: "")
    return y
}

arrayToString(["abc", "123"]) //"abc123"
```

Comment: Note that the `default` separator is `""`, so the function above simply does the same as a call directly to `joined()` from the array (`["abc", "123"].joined()`).